# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException occurred when convert Hibernate entity object to json

Tags: java, json, hibernate

There are two hibernate entity classes:

```
public class TUCollection implements java.io.Serializable,Comparable<TUCollection>{
    private TUUser TUUser;
    ...;
}

public class TUUser implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer userId;   //it is the main key of TUUser in the DB table
    private String img;
    private String email;
    ...;
}
```

And the TUCollection.hbm.xml has been writen as follow:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="cn.ssh.domain.TUCollection" table="t_u_collection" catalog="muyin_db">
        <id name="collId" type="integer">
            <column name="coll_id" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="TUUser" class="cn.ssh.domain.TUUser" fetch="select" foreign-key="none">
            <column name="user_id" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        ...
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

When I use net.sf.json.JSONObject convert object of TUUser to json:

```
JSONObject obj = JSONObject.fromObject(user); //user is a object of TUUser
```

It works well.But when I convert object of TUCollection to json:

```
JSONObject obj = JSONObject.fromObject(collect); //collectis a object of TUCollection
```

It cause a java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException exception. The stack information show as follow:

```
Hibernate: select tuuser0_.user_id as user1_12_0_, tuuser0_.img as img12_0_, tuuser0_.email as email12_0_, tuuser0_.password as password12_0_, tuuser0_.phonenum as phonenum12_0_, tuuser0_.username as username12_0_, tuuser0_.user_desc as user7_12_0_, tuuser0_.location as location12_0_, tuuser0_.type as type12_0_ from muyin_db.t_u_user tuuser0_ where tuuser0_.user_id=?
00:20:09,647 ERROR runtime:96 - 

Method public java.lang.String org.apache.commons.lang.exception.NestableRuntimeException.getMessage(int) threw an exception when invoked on net.sf.json.JSONException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
The problematic instruction:
----------
==> ${msg[0]} [on line 68, column 29 in org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/error.ftl]
----------

Java backtrace for programmers:
----------
freemarker.template.TemplateModelException: Method public java.lang.String org.apache.commons.lang.exception.NestableRuntimeException.getMessage(int) threw an exception when invoked on net.sf.json.JSONException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at freemarker.ext.beans.SimpleMethodModel.exec(SimpleMethodModel.java:130)
    at freemarker.ext.beans.SimpleMethodModel.get(SimpleMethodModel.java:138)
    at freemarker.core.DynamicKeyName.dealWithNumericalKey(DynamicKeyName.java:111)
    at freemarker.core.DynamicKeyName._getAsTemplateModel(DynamicKeyName.java:90)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.getAsTemplateModel(Expression.java:89)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.getStringValue(Expression.java:93)
    at freemarker.core.DollarVariable.accept(DollarVariable.java:76)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209)
    at freemarker.core.IfBlock.accept(IfBlock.java:82)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$Context.runLoop(IteratorBlock.java:179)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:416)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(IteratorBlock.java:102)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209)
    at freemarker.core.IfBlock.accept(IfBlock.java:82)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:189)
    at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.sendError(Dispatcher.java:748)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:505)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2441)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2430)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at freemarker.ext.beans.SimpleMemberModel.unwrapArguments(SimpleMemberModel.java:85)
    at freemarker.ext.beans.SimpleMethodModel.exec(SimpleMethodModel.java:106)
    ... 48 more
2015-10-19 0:20:09 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
Critical: Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/hia] threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendError(ResponseFacade.java:450)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.sendError(Dispatcher.java:752)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:505)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2441)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2430)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

However, when I use JsonConfig to filter TUUser to parse, converting TUCollection object to json works well. So, I think the above is related to TUUser.
Could anybody help me find the solution?
Thanks!